# Can one iOS mobile app use sync tables from several Azure App Service Mobile APPs?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to have one iOS App use synch tables from different Azure App Services Mobile App headends so that tables 1,2 and 3 comes from one App Service and tables 4,5 and 6 comes from another App Service?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have one iOS App use synch tables from different Azure App Services Mobile App headends

AFAIK, you could just create multiple `MSClient` instances as follows which point to your Azure Mobile Apps in your iOS App to sync tables from several Azure Mobile Apps.

```
MSClient *client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://{app1}.azurewebsites.net"];
```

For more details about using iOS client library for Azure Mobile Apps, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-how-to-use-client-library) and [Enable offline sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started-offline-data).

Additionally, for authentication users with social providers (e.g. AAD, Facebook, Twitter, Google, Microsoft Account, etc.) supported by azure app service, I would recommend you use the [Client-managed authentication flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow), and you could just create a single application with your social provider platform and use the same `App ID` and `App Secret` in your several Azure Mobile Apps. After the client user logged, you could leverage the token from the social provider and login with your Azure Mobile Apps. Details about authentication users, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-how-to-use-client-library#facebook-sdk).